# How many master-detail relationships per object?

Tags: relationships, master-detail, dev401

All I see online is that each object can have 2 master-detail relationships, but on the Salesforce App Limits PDF : https://na5.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

It says that custom objects can have 8, what release was this in? I am studying for DEV 401 and I wanted to make sure I knew the answer to this before I take it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only 2 Master Detail Relationship allowed per object and it can have upto three custom detail levels. 
You can read more about it here, [Considerations for Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Each object is allowed to have one or two masters, or up to 8 details.

Comment: Can you tell me where you read that you can have 8 details? Thanks

Comment: This is not limited to 8, there is no documentation --- can create 10+ without issue

Answer (score 2):

You can have a Total of 40 Relationship fields with a Maximum of 2 Master Detail Relationships.
So you can have all 40 as Lookup Relationship fields, 
38 Lookup and 2 MD
39 Lookup and 1 MD relationship fields on an object.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is 2 master-detail relationships on an object.  The purpose of this note is the reminder that the limits are placed on the *child* object.  Pretty obvious on an ER diagram; w/o ER in mind I for one will sometimes confuse where the limits are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Just created 4 master-details relationships, so it is certainly possible for a master to have more than 2 relationships.[image]

Comment: That's a different situation. Each object cannot be the _detail side_ of more than two master-detail relationships.

Answer (score 0):

A custom object cannot be on detail side for more than 2 Master-Detail relationships. It means any custom object can be involved in maximum 2 Master-Detail relationships as detail object.

Hope it answers your query!